# To decode json encoded value

Tags: php, android, json

```
return=array(1) {
  ["return"]=>
  string(142) "{"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"gallexy","price":"200.00","created_at":"2014-04-28 11:56:58","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}"
}
```

Above result is coming from server I am trying to decode with using but decode method but am failing again and again.

Comment: `$jsonArr = json_decode($yourArray['return'], TRUE);`

Comment: @AmalMurali it is giving me this result array(2) { ["products"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["pid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(7) "gallexy" ["price"]=> string(6) "200.00" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-04-28 11:56:58" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" } } ["success"]=> int(1) }

Comment: acutlly i want it in proper format like pid | 1, name|gallexy like this

Comment: @user3454782 now you have array format the array yourself whatever format you want.

Comment: @user3454782: That's the decoded JSON array. Now you can get the required value out of that array by accessing that specific index. For example, if you wanted to print out the keys and values, you can just do `foreach ($jsonArr['products'][0] as $key => $value) { echo "$key | $value<br />"; }`

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks sir i get the formatted out put.

Comment: @user3454782: You can post that as an answer and mark it as correct. Or you could delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode($return['return'], TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parameter `true` as the 2nd parameter in the "json_decode" function.

e.g `json_decode($json,true);`

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode, with the string as the first parameter. Putting true in the second paramenter makes the return a PHP array (multi-dimensional if needed), without this parameter it will be a PHP representation of a JSON object

```
$json_decoded = json_decode($return['return'], true);

//now you can use the array

myCoolFunction($json_decoded['products']);

myCoolFunction($json_decoded['products']['pid']);
```